# How to set up RestTemplate to retry calls on certain response status code?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-cloud

I’ve trouble setting up a RestTemplate to retry remote calls. Does anyone know how to configure the RestTemplate to retry calls after getting 503 response status code?

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: take a look here https://resilience4j.readme.io/

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible, you can try out custom retry policy.

```
class InternalServerExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy extends ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy {
public InternalServerExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy() {
    final SimpleRetryPolicy simpleRetryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
    simpleRetryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(3);

    this.setExceptionClassifier(new Classifier<Throwable, RetryPolicy>() {
        @Override
        public RetryPolicy classify(Throwable classifiable) {
            if (classifiable instanceof HttpServerErrorException) {
                // For 503
                if (((HttpServerErrorException) classifiable).getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE) {
                    return simpleRetryPolicy;
                }
                return new NeverRetryPolicy();
            }
            return new NeverRetryPolicy();
        }
    });
}}
```

Ans the simply call it as below:

```
RetryTemplate template = new RetryTemplate();
template.setRetryPolicy(new InternalServerExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy())
```

Answer (score 0):

Retry within the catch block

```
try {
    responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(endpoint, HttpMethod.POST, entity, MyResponse.class);
} catch (HttpClientErrorException hcee) {
    //There is an error in request, if known, improve and retry
} catch (HttpServerErrorException hsee) {
    recvdStatusCode = hsee.getStatusCode();
    // Handle it within a switch case, if there is an option to retry.
}
```

> This may be another approach, I have never tried this myself-

```
@Bean
  public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {

    int maxAttempt = Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("maxAttempt"));
    int retryTimeInterval = Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("retryTimeInterval"));

    SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
    retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(maxAttempt);

    FixedBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
    backOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(retryTimeInterval); // 1.5 seconds

    RetryTemplate template = new RetryTemplate();
    template.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
    template.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);

    return template;
  }
```

//Here is the invocation -

```
retryTemplate.execute(context -> {
        System.out.println("inside retry method");
        ResponseEntity<?> requestData = RestTemplateProvider.getInstance().postAsNewRequest(bundle, ServiceResponse.class, serivceURL,
                CommonUtils.getHeader("APP_Name"));

        _LOGGER.info("Response ..."+ requestData);
            throw new IllegalStateException("Something went wrong");
        });
```

Comment: Cannot do like that...cause I don t want to change all my service methods. So I basically need a way to define e RestTemplate spring bean configured to retry that calls

Comment: This may be another way to tackle the situation -